# Objective - C Core Data Modeling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, entity-framework

I am working with the core data model in Xcode 5 and I am trying to code an app for school that helps me determine my grades. I need the app to show a table view of each class and then when you select one, it takes you to the next page and from there you can add sections (ex. test, quiz, hw, etc.) and be able to add the percent and grade for each.

Now my question is, should I be using 2 entities or just 1? I was thinking two (class and section) and then just use multiple sections per class. But would anyone advise doing this? If so, how should I go about making the class entity the "parent" or the section entity? or maybe there is a way to do it with just one entity and work with multiple sections within it.. Any advice or answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two entities (Class, Section) and make one to many relationship between class and section. As each class may have multiple section, relationship is the good approach to do this.

class<---------->> Section

Refer this link for relationship sample.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/